# XML to List<string> C#

Tags: c#, xml, list

My problem is, I want to convert xml to list which I can compare with other list.

Here is code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
  <firstrun>false</firstrun>
  <kategorie>
    <firstrun>true</firstrun>
    <samochod>true</samochod>
    <samochod1111>true</samochod1111>
    <samochod22222>true</samochod22222>
  </kategorie>
  <stylkolor>1</stylkolor>
  <themekolor>1</themekolor>
</body>
```

and code in which I want to convert xml to list:

```
public List<string> wczytajListeKategorii()
{
    XElement xdoc = XElement.Load(fileName);

    var list = xdoc.Elements("kategorie");

    List<string> selectedCollection = list.ToList();

    return selectedCollection;
}
```

Unfotunatelly it doesn't work.

Thank you for help

Comment: Can you expand upon "doesn't work"? What is it doing?

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: I would recommend looking into the XML Serialization framework in .NET. You can turn your XML into an object and compare the members of the two classes. Starting with VS2013 you can Paste XML into the Editor window and have it generate a class based on the XML structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you exactly want to do but let met tell you that your code will not compile because of this line 
`List<string> selectedCollection = list.ToList();`

`list.ToList()`returns a collection od XElement type not a collection of string.

If you just want to retrive the value in each node in kategorie element this is what you want to do :

```
var list = xdoc.Elements("kategorie").Elements().Select(p => p.Value);
List<string> selectedCollection = list.ToList();
```

Comment: Or in one line, `List<string> list = xdoc.Elements("kategorie").Elements().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();`